# Chilli plant leaves disease

Tags: diseases, leaves, chili

My chilli plant leaves seem to get some white shiny spots on them and then go brown and die off. The pics don’t look like anything I’ve seen from googling; is it rescueable?

Thanks!

Malcolm

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know about the necrotic parts you asked about, but I do notice what looks like some thrip damage along the leaf veins.

Answer (score 0):

You may prune the plant, give it a little bit of epsom salt well diluted...(1tablespoon of epsom salt to a gallon of water) monthly and more sunlight. I believe your plant will pick up. That's the little i can offer.

Sorry...the above answer really works for yellow leaves of your chilly plant... I hope it works well too for the problem you mentioned.